# Wrap each word of a html content in a span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm not able to wrap each word of a html content with a span, keeping other markup as well.

For example,If my code sample is

`<p><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</b><br/> <a href="#">consectetur</a> adipiscing elit. Nam nec scelerisque nisl, vitae mattis diam. Proin fermentum lorem in interdum porttitor.</p>`

What I'm trying to do is (code which retains other elements as well)

```
<p><b><span class="sc">Lorem</span> <span class="sc">ipsum</span> <span class="sc">dolor</span> <span class="sc">sit</span></b><br/> <span class="sc">amet</span> <a hre=""><span class="sc">consectetur</span></a> <span class="sc">adipiscing</span> <span class="sc">elit.</span> <span class="sc">Nam</span> <span class="sc">nec</span> <span class="sc">scelerisque</span> <span class="sc">nisl,</span> <span class="sc">vitae</span> <span class="sc">mattis</span> <span class="sc">diam.</span> <span class="sc">Proin</span> <span class="sc">fermentum</span> <span class="sc">lorem</span> <span class="sc">in</span> <span class="sc">interdum</span> <span class="sc">porttitor.</span></p>
```

What I'm getting out of below Js code is

```
    <p><span class="sc">Lorem</span> <span class="sc">ipsum</span> <span class="sc">dolor</span> <span class="sc">sit</span> <span class="sc">amet</span> <span class="sc">consectetur</span> <span class="sc">adipiscing</span> <span class="sc">elit.</span> <span class="sc">Nam</span> <span class="sc">nec</span> <span class="sc">scelerisque</span> <span class="sc">nisl,</span> <span class="sc">vitae</span> <span class="sc">mattis</span> <span class="sc">diam.</span> <span class="sc">Proin</span> <span class="sc">fermentum</span> <span class="sc">lorem</span> <span class="sc">in</span> <span class="sc">interdum</span> <span class="sc">porttitor.</span></p>
```

As you can see I'm loosing the `<b></b>, <br/> <a/>` tag markups in my output.

My Javacript code,

```
var articleContent = "";
var totalWords = 0;
$("#content").find('p').each(function(){
    var text = $(this).text().split(' ');
    for( var i = 0, len = text.length; i<len; i++ ) {
        text[i] = '<span class="sc">'+text[i]+'</span>'; 
    }
    totalWords = totalWords + i;            
    articleContent = articleContent + "<p>"+text.join(' ')+"</p>";
});//End of each ,
console.log(articleContent);
```

Here is the fiddle for the same [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/balarajv/0oqasa8z/)

How to wrap each word in a span keeping other markup as well ?

We can assume that my HTML code my contain only `<b> </br> <a>` as other elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
$('p')
    .find('*')
    .addBack('p')
    .each(function () {

        textNode = $(this).contents().filter(function () {
           return this.nodeType === 3; //Node.TEXT_NODE
        });

        text = textNode.text().split(' ');
        replace = '';

        $.each(text, function (index, value) {
            if ( value.replace(/\s+/, "") ) {   // Remove whitespaces
               replace += '<span class="wraped">' + value + '</span>';          
            }
        });

        textNode.replaceWith( $(replace) );

    });
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/510nb9gr/)

Comment: It is giving wrong output. It prints the text twice.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `.text()` which is stripping all of the other markup. You are going to need to use regexps to do this I think as there are sometimes spaces within the tags that your split(' ') is finding.

So you need a regex that looks either for a string with a space at the end or a tag and its closing tag. That's not immediately straightforward.  This looks for the spaces:

```
text.replace(/(\w*)\s/g, "<span class="">$1</span> ")
```