# How to wrap SPAN tags to each word while retaining existing HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Say that I have this HTML:

```
<h2>The standard <strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> passage, used since the 1500s</h2>

<ul>
  <li>Praesent <strong>vehicula</strong> est id nibh <i>elementum</i> placerat.</li>
</ul>
```

And I need to wrap each word with `SPAN` while retaining existing HTML.

```
<h2><span>The</span> <span>standard</span> <strong><span>Lorem</span> <span>Ipsum</span></strong> <span>passage,</span> <span>used</span> <span>since</span> <span>the</span> <span>1500s</span></h2>

<ul>
  <li><span>Praesent</span> <strong><span>vehicula</span></strong> <span>est</span> <span>id</span> <span>nibh</span> <i><span>elementum</span></i> <span>placerat.</span></li>
</ul>
```

This JS just work fine for text but not for the text that has markup.

```
var fillInText = $('.my-html-editor').html().split(/ +/),
    lenA = fillInText.length,
    resultA = [];

for (var i = 0; i < lenA; i++) {
  resultA[i] = '<span>' + fillInText[i] + '</span>';
}

var joinedText = resultA.join(' ');

console.log(joinedText);
```

Comment: are you trying to replace the current file with those spans? or do that on some action?

Comment: I would use split() to separate the string into individual words, append the span, push the appended words into an array and concat the word strings in the array on the output.

var str = "This is a sentence.";
var words = str.split(" ");

Comment: What @Korgrue said, except it will be necessary to parse out the HTML tags before wrapping with `<span></span>` lest you get things like `<span><strong>Lorem</span>` which could prove problematic.

Comment: Define selectors on your `<span>` tags and do not use html tags to *style* your text. This will be much cleaner.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wrap each word of a html content in a span](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29730901/wrap-each-word-of-a-html-content-in-a-span)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to share what I did for this kind of problem. I hope this helps to narrow down the understanding.

```js
var x = document.querySelector('#content');
var y = x.textContent.trim().split(" ");
var obj = y.reduce(function(acc, cur, i) {
  cur = cur.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, "");
  if(cur !== ""){
   acc[cur] = cur;
  }
  return acc;
}, {});
var regEx=new RegExp(Object.keys(obj).join("|"),"gi");
var newC = x.innerHTML.replace(regEx,function(y){
 return "<span>"+y+"</span>";
})
console.log(newC);
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <h2>The standard <strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> passage, used since the 1500s</h2>

  <ul>
    <li>Praesent <strong>vehicula</strong> est id nibh <i>elementum</i> placerat.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: your code work fine even if there is class added to span. Thanks :)

Comment: @Syed glad that help :) the below actually will going to break because it checks the indexes. Mine is directly on the words:) welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Replacing all words that are not preceeded by a `<` or `</` seems to work:

```js
var text = document.getElementById("t1").value;
var repl = text.replace(/[\w,\.]+/g, (m, offset, str) => {
  if (str[offset - 1] == "<"
   || str[offset - 2] == "<") return m;
   else return "<span>"+m+"</span>";
});
document.getElementById("t2").value = repl;
```

```html
<textarea id="t1"><h2>The standard <strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> passage, used since the 1500s</h2>

<ul>
  <li>Praesent <strong>vehicula</strong> est id nibh <i>elementum</i> placerat.</li>
</ul></textarea>
<textarea id="t2"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked. I just did some change to match my requirement and replaced `textarea` with `div` and changed it to jQuery.
`var text = $(".t1").html();

var repl = text.replace(/[\w,\.]+/g, (m, offset, str) => {
  if (str[offset - 1] == "<"
   || str[offset - 2] == "<") return m;
   else return "<span>"+m+"</span>";
});

$(".t2").html(repl);`

Comment: if there is class added span to source HTML every thing will start breaking :(